# dtype error when fitting Sklearn Pipeline with a TargetEncoder followed by an XGBoost classifier

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, xgboost

I am having the following error when trying to fit a pipeline that uses a XGBoost classifier as its final steps:

> DataFrame.dtypes for data must be int, float or bool.
> Did not expect the data types in fields [Categorical Columns here].

I am using the following pipeline, with a TargetEncoder to encode the categorical columns:

```
numerical_transformer = MinMaxScaler()
categorical_transformer = TargetEncoder()

numerical_cols = X.select_dtypes(include=['float', 'int']).columns
categorical_cols = X.select_dtypes(include='object').columns

preprocessor = make_column_transformer(
    (categorical_transformer, categorical_cols),
    (numerical_transformer, numerical_cols),
    remainder='passthrough')

clf = XGBClassifier(objective= 'binary:logistic')

pipe = make_pipeline(preprocessor, clf)

pipe.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

The problem is that, apparently, the TargetEncoder sets *object* to the data types of the encoded categorical columns. An so, XGBoost throws the error.

So, how could I set the data type to, for example, *float* before it is used by the XGBClassifier object?

Comment: Can you can plug a [function transformer][1] after the categorical transformer, for example?


  [1]: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.FunctionTransformer.html#sklearn.preprocessing.FunctionTransformer

Comment: @ItamarMushkin Thanks for commenting. Using the function transformer I could verify that the TargetEncoder effectively sets _float64_ to all the encoded categorical columns. But then, the ColumnTransformer outputs an ndarray, and not a DataFrame. Somehow, the XGBoost classifier does not interpret those columns as floats!

Comment: 1. An SKLearn entity (transformer) can't be expected to output a DataFrame, and neither should it (XGBoost doesn't expect a DataFrame)

Comment: 2. Maybe you have None's in your input to XGBoost? Those pesky little None's don't 'break' the float dtype, but they are a problem to XGBoost.

Comment: I've used the column transformer to check if i could find some None, but it wasn't the case. The pipeline worked only when I used  a `FunctionTransformer(f)` where f does `return x.astype('float64)`. I still don't know what the problem was.

Comment: On the one hand the encoder supposedly casts to float, but on the other the pipeline only worked when you explicitly added a transformer to cast it to float... what a mystery. Anyway, you should write an answer with your solution and accept it (so others know it's closed)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find an explanation of what was the problem, but I will explain what I did to resolve it.

First, I checked if I could find some NaN or None values in the output of the pipeline when discarding the last step:

```
pipe = Pipeline(my_pipeline.steps[:-1])
X_trans = pipe.fit_transform(X,y)
print(f'nb of nan: {np.isnan(X_trans).sum()}')
print(f'nb of none: {(r == None).sum()}')  
>>> nb of nan: 0
>>> nb of none: 0
```

So, as there doesn't seem to be a problem with the data, I choose to use a FunctionTransformer, as recommended by [Itamar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8874696/itamar-mushkin), to force the dtype to float. The pipeline now looks like this:

```
pipe = make_pipeline(preprocessor, 
                     FunctionTransformer(lambda x: x.astype('float64')), 
                     clf)
```

And with this, the problem disappeared.